# How to prevent non-optarg args to Bash function?

Tags: bash, getopts

I've got a Bash function for using a select statement with `git checkout`. It works fine. I'd like to prevent a use case, and I'm not sure how. How can I prevent non-optarg values being passed to the function as `"$1"`. For example:

1. `$ gco hello` should no-op since `hello` is not associated with a `-b` flag. <-- Need to implement
2. `$ gco -b hello` should check out the branch `hello`. <-- Working
3. `$ gco` should present the `select` menu. <-- Working

As expected, checking for `"$1"` isn't the answer because it messes with potential optargs.

```
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "$1"
        return
    fi
```

```
gco () {
    local branch=""

    while getopts :hb: opt; do
        case "$opt" in
            h) 
                echo "NAME:     gco - git branch to check out."
                echo "SYNOPSYS: gco [-b branch]"
                echo "-h        Display help text."
                echo "-b        branch"
                return
                ;;
            b) branch="$OPTARG" ;;
            :) echo "Missing argument for option -$OPTARG"; return 1 ;;
           \?) echo "Unknown option -$OPTARG"; return 1 ;;
        esac
    done

    if [ "$branch" != "" ]; then
        git checkout "$branch"
        return
    fi

    echo "Which branch would you like to check out?"
    select b in $(git branch | sed 's/* /  /'); do
        git checkout "$b"
        return
    done
}
```

Comment: Regarding `How can I prevent non-optarg values being passed to the function as "$1"` - why do you want to do that rather than having the function handle whatever args it's passed? Having the code that calls gco parse the input to figure out what it can/can't pass to gco and then having gco parse the input for what it expects seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: By the way the `/* /` in `sed 's/* /  /'` is undefined behavior as that's a regexp repetition metachar `*` at the start of a regexp so there's nothing before it to repeat. Some seds may treat it like a literal `*` while others might ignore it or do anything else. If you intend the `*` to be treated literally then explicitly make it literal with `sed 's/\* /  /'` or if you intended it to mean something else then tell us what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical for using [getopts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-getopts) is to 'shift' the parsed options after getopts finished. So after your while loop you can do

```
 shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

to remove all parsed options. `OPTIND` indicates the next option getopts would check so after the loop it points to the first non-option. As example when calling your function with

```
gco -b master
  # OPTIND is 3 after the while loop
gco hello
  # OPTIND is 1 after the while loop
```

Now you actually can check for `$1` if they are more non-opt args or in your case it is probably enough to

```
[[ $# == 0 ]] || return
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a generic option processor alone, you cannot detect the case when an argument is missing the option. E.g. the user wanted `gco -b hello` but forgot the `-b`. The case `gco hello` looks like there are no options, followed by a non-option argument.

If the program *has* no non-option arguments, then that's the way the error will be handled.

```
gco: error, unexpected "hello" argument: option expected.
```

If the program has non-option arguments, but they have to have certain characteristics (like having to be names of existing files), then it will go that way:

```
gco: no such path: "hello".
```

Beyond that your program can try *ad hoc* heuristics. It can notice that a file was not found, but `hello` happens to be the name of a branch.

```
gco: no such path: "hello".
gco: there is a branch "hello". Did you mean -b "hello"?
```

or

```
gco: unexpected non-option argument: "hello"
gco: there is a branch "hello". Did you mean -b "hello"?
```

Option parsers typically deal with the options. They process known ones, flag unknown ones and then leave the non-option arguments for the program to handle.